# Get img tags which have the same src and rel in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I get all the `<img>` tags which have the same values in their `src` and `rel` attributes?

I've tried something like:

```
jQuery('img[rel=src]')
```

But it doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`.filter` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
$('img').filter(function() {
    return this.src === $(this).attr('rel');
});
```

Note that `rel` is not a valid attribute for `img` elements. Therefore you might want to use [`data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to store the additional information.

**Additional note**: `this.src` will return the *absolute* URL, even if the `src` attribute contains a relative URL. If you want to get the actual value of the attribute, you have to use `$(this).attr('src')`.

Comment: I already am using `data-original`, rel was just for simplicity of the post. Works like a charm, thanks! Didn't even know about the existence of `.filter`, so I guess I still have a lot to learn :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) If you have some time, just browse through the jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/), you might discover amazing things ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it :

```html
<img src="../images/images/map_ico.png" rel="../images/images/map_ico.png" alt="logo" />   
<img src="../images/images/map_ico.png" alt="logo" />
<img src="../images/images/map_ico.png" rel="../images/images/map_ico.png" alt="logo" />
```

```js
var imgs=[];
$('img').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('src')==$(this).attr('rel')){
        imgs.push($(this))
    }
})
//would return 2
alert(imgs.length);
```

The imgs array will now hold all the image tags that have the same src and alt attributes.